# google script to trigger github workflow, code 404 error

Tags: google-apps-script, github-actions

I want to trigger a github workflow from a google form.

I first tested github side using curl and it worked fine. Now I want to do the same using google script. here is my code

```
  const data = {"ref": "main"};

  var options = {
    method: "post",
    header: {authorization: 'token <MY_TESTED_GITHUB_TOKEN>'},
    payload: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/<ID>/<MY_REPO>/actions/workflows/new_request.yml/dispatches", options);
```

This returns the following error message:

Exception: Request failed for https://api.github.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Answer (score 1):

From your error message, I guessed that you wanted to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://docs.github.com/ja/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28)

```
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"topic-branch","inputs":{"name":"Mona the Octocat","home":"San Francisco, CA"}}'
```

When I saw your showing script, it seems that the request of your script might be different from the above curl command.
In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please modify `data`, `url`, and your access token for your actual situation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches";
  const data = {"ref":"topic-branch","inputs":{"name":"Mona the Octocat","home":"San Francisco, CA"}};
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>",
      "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28",
      "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

- I think that the request of this Google Apps Script is the same with the above curl command. But, if this was not your expected result, can you provide your curl command of `I first tested github side using curl and it worked fine.`? By this, I would like to modify the script.

#### References:

- [Create a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/ja/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thank you, your code works fine.  This was my curl command:

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token <toekn>" <url> -d '{"ref":"main"}'

Comment: @ultrafrog About `Thank you, your code works fine.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer